# Let me know how to solve 'ignoreFirst' error of function or variable with matlab code

Tags: matlab

Currently, I'm creating something using MATLAB. However, an error occured that I do not understand

```
for n = 1:beats
  [time, X] = modelRunner(X0, options, param, beats, ignoreFirst);
X0 = X(size(X,1),:);
n % output beat number to the screen to monitor runtime progress
end
```

Error code is:

```
##Error Message
ignoreFirst is function or variable not to detect.


Error occurring: torord_qNet (line 73)
[time, X] = modelRunner(X0, options, param, beats, ignoreFirst);
```

Please, let me know how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

`ignoreFirst` is not native to MATLAB. It is either not defined (as a variable) or it is not on your [search path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html) -- if it is a function or script.